# Oracle Exalogic/Exadata Performance tracker

Tags: performance, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g, exadata

Recently we have migrated our application to Oracle Engineered Systems- EXALOGIC and EXADATA.
Performance of our application since then is appreciable.

However we would like to benchmark the performance of our application on Exalogic stack. It will be helpful if someone can tell us about the factors to be considered to effectively measure the application performance.

Few things i can think of are as below, i appreciate if you can add to the list.

1. Request/Response Time
2. Transaction time
3. Number of concurrent users

Are there any open source tools to benchmark application performance?

Answer (score 0):

The choice of optimal benchmarking tool depends on the application that you are benchmarking. Its hard to recommend anything when you have not even provided any details about the application.

You could for example use [Faban](http://faban.org/) - it is a free and open source performance workload creation and execution framework.